# How can I connect a table with two foreign keys to another table?

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect two Users based on their Interests. The connection table consists of a FirstUserId, a SecondUserId and an InterestId. Currently, it is possible to show the connection where I can get the information of the first user. I also want to be able to get the information of the second user, so their name and information can be shown. However, when trying to create a relationship between SecondUserId and Id (from the User table), I get the message that it is not possible because there already is an existing relationship.

I am wondering if anyone has a solution to how to connect SecondUserId to the User table. Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot of the relation in PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amSEm.png)

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning of SecondUserId in this case?
I.e. why do you want to have such connection?

Comment: The Connection table serves as a way to connect two users with each other based on their Interest. The FirstUserId and SecondUserId are necessary to connect them to each other based on said interest.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to connect two rows of one table via another table. It is not correct approach because you can't reference foreign key to the same table twice. (It does not make sense)
This approach can be used to connect two tables (such as table User + Interest)

Actually, you don't need to define additional things for the connection you want. It might be done via query. I.e. to get two users with the same interest:

```
select * from User where Id in (
    select FirstUserId from Connection where InterestId in (
        select InterestId from Connection
        group by InterestId having count(*) > 1
    )
)
```

or `having count(*) = 2` if you need exactly two users with the same interest